# django image preload action - read image geo-metatags

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm new in Django and this forum. I have a -problem with preload action. I have model:

```
class Observations(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    dateandtime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='dateAndTime', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    observer = models.ForeignKey('Observers', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='observer', blank=True, null=True)
    alpolcode = models.CharField(db_column='alpolCode', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/observations/")
```

and form:

```
class ObservationsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    dateandtime = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=DateTimePicker(
            options={
                'useCurrent': True,
                'collapse': False,
            },
            attrs={
                'append': 'fa fa-calendar',
                'icon_toggle': True,
            }
        ),
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Observations
        fields = [ 'lat', 'lon','dateandtime','observer','alpolcode', 'image']
```

In the fields lat and lon form store geographic longitude and latitude. I want create action that
read before save to database form data read image geolocation metatags (if available of course).
Any hint will be helpful.

Best regards,
Maciej

Any hint will be helpful